# Preciso de um programa que descubra a quantidade de ocorrências de todas letras de uma frase

Tags: python

Preciso de um programa que descubra a quantidade de ocorrências de todas letras de uma frase, e que coloque a letra e quantidade ocorrencias da mesma em um dicionário, chave:valor, respectivamente letra:ocorrencia.